# Problem Using JD Font

Tags: fonts

I would like to use the JD font in LaTeX documents. When I try to typeset the following example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Words. {\ECFJD More words.}

\end{document}
```

I get the error message

```
! Font T1/fjd/m/n/10=fjdmw8t at 10.0 pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

I am using TeXShop on a Mac OS 10.6. I downloaded the `zip` file for the font at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/emerald/, and it is in the following directory: `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex`. I don't know anything about installing fonts and assume I've done it wrong, but I have no idea how to make it work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: A lot of TeX distributions (TeX Live for example) don't include the emerald fonts. Are you sure that your distribution does?

Comment: You will have to put the files in the zip in the correct places. `tfm` e.g. should go to `/texmf/fonts/tfm/emerald/`. Check your main texmf tree for the various file types. Run `texhash` after you have moved the files. At the end you will have to enable the map, probably with `updmap-sys --enable emerald.map`.

Comment: Thanks for your help--I didn't realize I had to run some commands in Terminal. In case this helps anyone else, here were the three things I did which made this work: create the string of folders `local/texlive/texmf-local` in my user folder; copy all files inside the unzipped `Emerald` folder into this `texmf-local` folder; and run the following in Terminal: `texhash` followed by `sudo -H updmap-sys --enable Map=emerald.map` followed by `texhash` again. The font is now functional!

Comment: @canageek: emerald shouldn't be in _any_ tex distribution, given that the fonts don't all have the same licence (or they were when i was classifying the bindle for the ctan catalogue).

Comment: @wasteofspace iirc, they are in MiKTeX by default. I might’ve had to make their map available manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the font working by placing it into your local `texmf` directory: Copy all files inside the unzipped `Emerald` folder into `local/texlive/texmf-local` in your user folder. If this folder is not existent, you can simply create it. Then run the following in Terminal: `texhash` followed by `sudo -H updmap-sys --enable Map=emerald.map` followed by `texhash` again. The font should now be functional!

Comment: Awesome. Are there any resources you could point me to to better understand what's going on with those magical commands? Thanks!

Comment: @Will Take a look at [this link](https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html) for an explanation of what the commands are doing.