# Once-working font broken after distribution update

Tags: fonts

Two years ago I successfully installed the `emerald` package of fonts using the directions at [Installing TeX fonts](https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html) and [some help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79926/problem-using-jd-font) from the StackExchange. I updated my MacTeX distribution about six months ago, and have discovered that the fonts no longer work. The log for test file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Words. {\ECFJD More words.}

\end{document}
```

reports

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode ljfour --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 fjdmw8r
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for fjdmw8r.
mktexpk: perhaps fjdmw8r is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
/usr/texbin/dvips: Font fjdmw8r not found; using cmr10
```

I've checked that all the `emerald` files are in the right directories, and tried re-running the Terminal commands used to install the font, but that doesn't correct the problem.

Comment: Add `\pdfmapfile{=emerald.map}` and compile with pdflatex (!). If it works add the map file to your system (probably with `updmap-sys --enable emerald.map`).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Adding `\pdfmapfile{=emerald.map}` works beautifully, and I use these fonts rarely enough that I'm happy just to do that every time. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I think I've already added the map file to the system. Running `updmap-sys --enable Map=emerald.map` returns several lines ending with
`/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.`